# sympy - parametric limit

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

Say I would like to solve a parametric limit: in the following example, `alpha > 0` is the parameter.

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.symbols("x", real=True)
alpha = sp.symbols("alpha", real=True, positive=True, nonzero=True)
expr = (x * sp.exp(x) - sp.exp(2 * sp.sqrt(1 + x**2))) / (sp.exp(alpha * x) + x** alpha)
sp.limit(expr, x, sp.oo)
```

If I execute the code I get the result `-oo`, which is arguably incorrect.

If I were to compute this limit by hand I would look at the numerator and conclude that `exp(2 * sp.sqrt(1 + x**2))` is of the same order of `exp(2*x)`, which dominates `x * exp(x)`. Similarly, looking at the denominator I would say that `exp(alpha * x)` dominates the term `x**alpha`.

Therefore, I can compute the limit of the function `-exp((2 - alpha) * x)`. The correct result would be:

```
-oo for 0 < alpha < 2
-1 for alpha = 2
0 for alpha > 2
```

Is there an *easy* way to achieve this result with sympy?

Answer (score 1):

This should be considered a bug in SymPy. I would suggest opening an issue about it https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues.

Regarding what you are asking for in general, it isn't implemented yet. See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13312.